# Ensuring unique Javascript identifiers in ASP.NET Web User Controls

Tags: asp.net, javascript

In my current project, I am creating a number of user controls, some of which include some custom Javascript for event handling on the client side. I am registering my event handlers using OnClientClick="function()" and the like.

Now, I'm wondering how to ensure that all Javascript function names are unique for each specific instance of the control, so I don't risk name conflicts between controls. I have thought about putting all functions inside a named object, like

```
var <%=ClientID%>_Script {
  method1: function() { ...}
}
```

and then subscribing to events using something like

```
OnClientClick="<%=ClientID%>_Script.methodName()"
```

It just seems like I can't but <%= %>-expressions inside OnClient* attributes. I am therefore wondering; are there some "best practices" for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest solution might be to simply have a generic event handler which delegates to the appropriate handler:

```
OnClientClick="handleClick(this)"
```

`this` in the scope of the `onclick` attribute is the current element being clicked.

The ASP.NET way would be to [register the client script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hc29e2a.aspx). Specifically, see their recommendations under **Referencing Controls Rendered Inside Other Controls** (create script dynamically and register it.)